# Equality between maximal matching and minimum vertex cover

Tags: graph-theory

If M is a minimum vertex cover of a graph $G=(V,E)$ and $M^* $  denotes   the smallest maximal matching of G,

I need to find and infinite family of graphs  such that $|M| = 2|M^*|$ for any graph G of the family. I know that for every graph the inequality $|M|  \leq 2|M^*|$ holds and  I was able to notice that the equality holds for the Petersen's graph but I have not been able to find a family.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Complete graphs on an odd number of vertices.